# What is the name for adding properties and functions to an object at runtime in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript it is possible to add both properties and functions to objects (and functions) dynamically? What is the name for this?

```
var obj = {};
obj.myProperty = "I have just beed added!";
```

Comment: sounds like a homework question...

Comment: @danwellman It's a valid quesiton. Things generally have names, duck typing, hoisting, closures, modules, duck typying, memoization...

Comment: I'm not saying homework questions *are* bad, we've all got to learn right? It was just an observation. And it wasn't me that down-voted the question, although I did upvote one of the answers...

Comment: @danwellman If you can't answer the question just leave it.  Or if you think it is a homework question say why.

Comment: @danwellman: Since you decided to post your observation as a comment, I take it you felt that it was relevant in some way?

Comment: Surely that's *exactly* what comments are for...

Comment: @danwellman: I really have no idea what you mean. *What* is "exactly" what comments are for? *Why* do you think it's relevant that this is a homework question (if it is)?

Comment: @ruakh Comment: *A remark expressing an opinion or reaction* . Surely you have seen far worse comments in your time on SO? I know I have. It was an observation, nothing more. I am free to leave comments, as are you. You are free to flag comments if you wish. Honestly, I can't see why it means so much to you. Besides, the question had very little substance, and sounds like it was read straight out of a text-book.

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript, everything is always made at runtime.

So I'd call it *"adding properties and functions to an object"*.

Answer (score 1):

Just to contribute to the sum of knowledge, as I now feel bad about my comment re homework...

This is known simply as **property assignment** because you are assigning a value to a property.

#### EDIT:

For the record, section 3 of chapter 3: Objects, in *JavaScript the good parts* by Douglas Crockford, states thus:

> A value in an object can be updated by **assignment**. If the property
> name already exists in the object, the property value is replaced

(emphasis added)

Comment: Not really.  Because that covers properties that already exist? I think augmentation is better.

Comment: @dublintech Yes really. *Types* in JavaScript are things like numbers, strings, arrays and objects. Based on *what the OP actually posted* my answer is correct. Or at least no less correct than any of the others. Except for yours which is completely incorrect...

Comment: it does not relaly differentiate between properties that are already there and properties are not thou. Does it?

Comment: No, it doesn't. But then neither does JavaScript - if the property doesn't exist, it is created and the value *assigned*, if it does exist the value is *assigned* as the new value. It is still called property assignment. Type augmentation is a *completely* different thing altogether

Comment: some good points.  Don't want to be petty over this. I think it is unclear whether "augmentation" or property assignment is a better term.

Comment: Bit late for that. It's completely clear to me. Augmenting a type **is** a different thing. When you add a custom method to the array type, for example, array.prototype.myMethod = function() { ... }; *that* is augmenting the array *type*. Can you not see that is completely different from assigning a property to an object, e.g. myObject.myProp = "myValue"; ?! Even using them is different; augmented type: [0,1,2].myMethod() vs accessing an object property: val = myObject.myProp; I've even shown you the correct passage in the book you tried to use as reference!

Comment: Thanks. If I am correct, I think you think that augmentation is always about changing or adding to the prototype. I don't think it is clear in the Crockford book that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is prototype based language so you can call it as prototype behavior.

Comment: @Shusi Thanks, But I think that's more confusing because when you add like I have done in example no-one will inherit anything. But when you add to a prototype there is inheritance.

Comment: Stricly speaking, it's more about sharing at first than about inheritance.

Answer (score -1):

**Augmenting Types**: Crockford Page 32, 'JavaScript the Good Parts'.  SO I guess we could call this: *augmentation*.  He goes on to talk about augmenting the prototype but in the opening paragraph he says:

"JavaScript allows the basic types of the language to be *augmented*.   In chapter 3, we saw that adding a method to Object.prototype makes that method available to all objects. This **also** works for functions, arrays strings, numbers, regular expressions and booleans."

He then goes on to give examples of augmenting the prototype. But, as the sentence above shows augmenting can be applied to all JavaScript basic types.

So I guess augmenting is a fair enough word.

Comment: If you're referring to authority, would you be graceful enough to include a citation or a link ?

Comment: OP's case is really different from the augmentation of prototype. I don't see why we should speak of type as what is enriched is an instance (contrary to a type).

Comment: I can't believe you criticised my comment, which was just an off-hand comment, and then left a completely inaccurate answer!

Comment: @dystroy I have edited to make clearer.Augmenting can be done with prototypes and other JavaScript basic types.

Comment: >< type augmentation !== property assignment. And, the proto*type* is not the same as a *type* in JavaScript. The prototype is the object that other objects inherit from. You can augment types *using* the prototype of the type in question, but that is completely different from what the OP actually asked